# Maxima- symbolic variable substitution in more algorithmic way

Tags: algorithm, substitution, maxima

```
expJ:listarray(J);

(expJ)  ["-(l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t))+(2*l[1]*l[2]*m[3]+l[1]*l[2]*m[2])*('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))-l[1]*m[1]*g*cos(r[1](t)))/2","-(l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t))+((-2*l[1]*l[2]*m[3])-l[1]*l[2]*m[2])*('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))-2*l[2]*m[2]*g*cos(r[2](t)))/2","(l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t))+l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t))+3*l[3]*m[3]*g*cos(r[3](t)))/2"]
for i:1 thru 3 do(
    for k:1 thru 3 do(
J[i,1]:ssubst("m3","m[3]",J[i,1])
));
```

I wanna substitute numbers in front of m as they are 1,2,3 with algorithm, but when I put mi ,it recognizes this as different variable, so somehow I need to indicate ssubs("mi","m[i]",J[i,1]) as i is separate from m.
 Any suggestions?

Comment: String operations on mathematical expressions in Maxima are almost never the right thing to do. What is the larger goal that you are trying to achieve? Maybe you don't need to substitute `mi` for `m[i]` at all -- for many purposes, subscripted variables are treated the same as non-subscripted.

Comment: I need to eliminate [] brackets because I will copy and paste my result of J matrix to MATLAB. As you know [] is causing problem in MATLAB. Actually I can change m1 with m[1] ,m2 with m[2] etc. ,but it is too much time-consuming. I need a algorithmic way to change all in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here is a way to substitute `v(k)` for `v[k]`. I believe that's OK since Matlab recognizes parentheses for array subscripts.

%o5 is the input (as strings) which you gave above. I've parsed the strings in %o7 and extracted the list of subscripted variables (via `sublist` and `subvarp`) in %o10. From there I created a list `v(k) = v[k]` in %o14 and then substituted those back into the parsed expressions in %o15.

I hope that this is going in the direction that will be helpful to you. You might still need to modify this approach to get what you want, but in any event, I will repeat my very strong advice against string processing. If there is still something more to do, it is almost certainly better to achieve it by working with expressions than with strings.

```
(%o5) [-(l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t))+(2*l[1]*l[\
2]*m[3]+l[1]*l[2]*m[2])*('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))-l[1]*m[1]*\
g*cos(r[1](t)))/2, -(l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t)\
)+((-2*l[1]*l[2]*m[3])-l[1]*l[2]*m[2])*('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1]\
(t))-2*l[2]*m[2]*g*cos(r[2](t)))/2, (l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin\
(r[3](t)-r[2](t))+l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t))+3\
*l[3]*m[3]*g*cos(r[3](t)))/2]
(%i6) linel:65;
(%o6)                          65
(%i7) map (parse_string, %o5);
                     d          2
(%o7) [((- l  l  m  (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t)))
            1  3  3  dt   3            3       1
                            d          2
 - (2 l  l  m  + l  l  m ) (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t))
       1  2  3    1  2  2   dt   2            2       1
                                        d          2
 + l  m  g cos(r (t)))/2, ((- l  l  m  (-- (r (t)))
    1  1        1              2  3  3  dt   3
                                                    d          2
 sin(r (t) - r (t))) - ((- 2 l  l  m ) - l  l  m ) (-- (r (t)))
      3       2               1  2  3     1  2  2   dt   1
 sin(r (t) - r (t)) + 2 l  m  g cos(r (t)))/2, 
      2       1          2  2        2
           d          2
(l  l  m  (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t))
  2  3  3  dt   2            3       2
             d          2
 + l  l  m  (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t))
    1  3  3  dt   1            3       1
 + 3 l  m  g cos(r (t)))/2]
      3  3        3
(%i8) grind (%);

[((-l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t)))
  -(2*l[1]*l[2]*m[3]+l[1]*l[2]*m[2])
   *('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))
  +l[1]*m[1]*g*cos(r[1](t)))
  /2,
 ((-l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t)))
  -((-2*l[1]*l[2]*m[3])-l[1]*l[2]*m[2])
   *('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))
  +2*l[2]*m[2]*g*cos(r[2](t)))
  /2,
 (l[2]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t))
  +l[1]*l[3]*m[3]*('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t))
  +3*l[3]*m[3]*g*cos(r[3](t)))
  /2]$
(%o8)                         done
(%i9) listofvars (%o7);
(%o9)            [l , m , g, t, l , m , m , l ]
                   1   1         2   2   3   3
(%i10) sublist (%, subvarp);
(%o10)              [l , m , l , m , m , l ]
                      1   1   2   2   3   3
(%i11) map (op, %o10);
(%o11)                 [l, m, l, m, m, l]
(%i12) map (args, %o10);
(%o12)           [[1], [1], [2], [2], [3], [3]]
(%i13) map (lambda ([v], apply (op(v), args(v))), %o10);
(%o13)        [l(1), m(1), l(2), m(2), m(3), l(3)]
(%i14) map (lambda ([v1, v2], v1=v2), %o10, %o13);
(%o14) [l  = l(1), m  = m(1), l  = l(2), m  = m(2), m  = m(3), 
         1          1          2          2          3
                                                       l  = l(3)]
                                                        3
(%i15) subst (%, %o7);
                            d          2
(%o15) [((- l(1) l(3) m(3) (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t)))
                            dt   3            3       1
                                        d          2
 - (2 l(1) l(2) m(3) + l(1) l(2) m(2)) (-- (r (t)))
                                        dt   2
 sin(r (t) - r (t)) + l(1) m(1) g cos(r (t)))/2, 
      2       1                        1
                    d          2
((- l(2) l(3) m(3) (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t)))
                    dt   3            3       2
                                            d          2
 - ((- 2 l(1) l(2) m(3)) - l(1) l(2) m(2)) (-- (r (t)))
                                            dt   1
 sin(r (t) - r (t)) + 2 l(2) m(2) g cos(r (t)))/2, 
      2       1                          2
                 d          2
(l(2) l(3) m(3) (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t))
                 dt   2            3       2
                   d          2
 + l(1) l(3) m(3) (-- (r (t)))  sin(r (t) - r (t))
                   dt   1            3       1
 + 3 l(3) m(3) g cos(r (t)))/2]
                      3
(%i16) grind (%);

[((-l(1)*l(3)*m(3)*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t)))
  -(2*l(1)*l(2)*m(3)+l(1)*l(2)*m(2))
   *('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))
  +l(1)*m(1)*g*cos(r[1](t)))
  /2,
 ((-l(2)*l(3)*m(3)*('diff(r[3](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t)))
  -((-2*l(1)*l(2)*m(3))-l(1)*l(2)*m(2))
   *('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[2](t)-r[1](t))
  +2*l(2)*m(2)*g*cos(r[2](t)))
  /2,
 (l(2)*l(3)*m(3)*('diff(r[2](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[2](t))
  +l(1)*l(3)*m(3)*('diff(r[1](t),t,1))^2*sin(r[3](t)-r[1](t))
  +3*l(3)*m(3)*g*cos(r[3](t)))
  /2]$
(%o16)                        done
(%i17) listofvars (%o15);
(%o17)                       [g, t]
```

Comment: your help is highly appreciated.Although this way is little bit complicated, I will look through it line by line

Comment: I'll be glad to explain any part that seems unclear.